# JAX-RPC support in Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: web-services, plugins, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, jax-rpc

I am trying to generate new Web Service Client. When choosing Client Style to JAX-RPC Style I get a notification from Netbeans: "You must download JAX-RPC support plugin to create a JAX-RPC Client".

Plugin is not listed in Available Plugins.
I searched topics regarding this issue and they are saying to add this address to search for available plugins:

http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

The problem is, link is dead.
Are there any other possibilities to solve this or does anyone have a working link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some network configuration changes that might have affected this.

I had looked at the Hudson results for nbms-and-javadoc a few days ago.

Your best bet is to try it tomorrow...

Comment: The url in the original post is functioning 'normally' now.

Answer (score 10):

Original poster - Thank you for the link! It worked perfectly for me today!

Version: NetBeans 6.9.1
Tools -> Plugins
Click "Settings" tab and "add" button
Provide a name (ex. Hudson) and the URL above in the original post
(http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz)
Close the dialog box
Click on Reload Catalog and click the "Available Plugins" tab
Find your JAX-RPC plugin goodness in the list, select its checkbox, and click "Install" :-)

Thanks again!!!

Comment: After installing this plugin mi Netbeans can´t start. Any idea?