# Adding new web services in Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, api, swing, netbeans

I am trying to build a myspace application in java using netbeans where the app. tries to update my account, friends updates and all that kind of stuff. There is a similar tutorial on nebeans site for twitter. But when I try adding the API address of [Myspace api](http://developer.myspace.com/wordpress/) it shows error "Cannot determine if the service is of type WSDL or WADL" and says to install JAX-RPC plugin.

I am using NB 6.9.1 and apparently I found out that this version of netbeans doesn't support JAX-RPC plugin anymore. Please help me on how to proceed with this.

Comment: goto `tools> plugin > available plugin > search for JAX-RPC` It must be there

Comment: Please refer to this similar question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581206/jax-rpc-support-in-netbeans-6-9-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581206/jax-rpc-support-in-netbeans-6-9-1)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Netbeans at lesast for WADL (REST style) described here:
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=163155

At least with Netbeans 7.1.1 I found a workaround for http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/api/application.wadl

I had to download the WADL and replace

```
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
```

with

```
<application xmlns="http://research.sun.com/wadl/2006/10">
```

Then I could import the description from the file.

I added a patch at the bug which should resolve this issue, so you may consider voting for this bug.