# Add SugarCRM REST services to NetBeans

Tags: web-services, rest, netbeans, sugarcrm

I'm trying to use NetBeans "Add Web Service" wizard to see SugarCRM REST web services. But when I insert url 'http://ip/sugarcrm/service/v2/rest.php' (or 'http://ip/sugarcrm/service/v2/rest.php?wadl') I receive the error message:

- "cannot determine if the service is of type wsdl or wadl".

I have already included JAX-RPC plugin, as mentioned in 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762149/adding-new-web-services-in-netbeans', but this not helped. In fact, I think NetBeans doesn't need RPC plugins to connecto to REST services...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Sugar uses the same methods and types for both SOAP and Rest. Can Netbeans interpret a soap wsdl for rest purposes?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in NetBeans 'Add Web Services' wizard, it shows the information "Specify the web service, or REST resources, descriptor file (WSDL or WADL file)". And below that message we can put the path to a local file or an url.

Comment: Well when I go to my instance of Sugar (Which is Pro 6.2.something), and go to /services/v2/rest.php I get a description. Not sure if it's WADL.  It's definitely not XML (at least not like I  know it).  But it's also a bit too normalized to be just be friendly documentation.  If Netbeans requires WSDL or WADL, both of which are XML, I don't think you can link up.  However I'd try the SOAP wsdl first.

Comment: I found 'YahooSearch.wadl', and this is a XML file, in fact. ".../services/v2/rest.php" is not like that... But I don't know if this url, used to access Sugar REST services, does the job of connecting to existing WADL files. What does NetBeans means when it says "Specify the web service, or REST resources, descriptor file (WSDL or WADL file)"??... All I need is a list of Sugar REST services, to connect and test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using the correct URLs.

One of the URLs in your post: http://ip/sugarcrm/service/v2/rest.php -> is trying to go to a host called "ip". Is that a host in your network? If not, then its going nowhere.

Comment: Hi Bill. The host 'ip' is not the "real" ip I use. It's "10.10.xx.xx" something. An internal IP in VPN. In browser, that URL shows to me the content of 'rest.php' page.

Comment: If you hit that URL with your browser, do you get a wadl?

Comment: No, it's not a WADL or XML file, like I said to Anthony. Just a PHP file, I suppose. Begins with: Class [  class SugarRestServiceImpl extends SugarWebServiceImpl ] {...}. But that URL is the entry point to REST services (http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/5.5/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_5.5-Chapter%202%20Application%20Framework.html) and I didn't found any way to access a WADL file.

Comment: The php file could return xml content.