# NetBeans doesn't start after installing JAX-RPC plugin

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, jax-rpc

Before marking my question as duplicate, I have gone through these questions

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277305/cannot-start-netbeans-8-0-1-after-jax-rpc-web-services-plugin-installation)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581206/jax-rpc-support-in-netbeans-6-9-1)

[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972418/how-do-i-enable-jax-rpc-web-services-plugin-in-netbeans-8-0)

But still no luck.

I have been trying since 1 week now, tried every possible solution on the internet but after installing `JAX-RPC` plugin from this link

http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

`NetBeans` won't start, I've tried this on NetBeans(6.9, 7.1, 7.3, 7.4, 8.0) no matter what I do NetBeans won't start after installing the `JAX-RPC` plugin !
Any help or work around would be appreciated.

In case if its relevant I'm using the following:

windows 7, 64-bit

java 7, 64 bit

If I still don't get a solution then its Goodbye to NetBeans !

Comment: Are you sure you are adding it correctly? A [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcLb6t8_OBA) suggests it works on NB 8.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already gone through the same process in the `youtube` video you mentioned about more than 100 times, uninstalling `netbeans` after each attempt, since it doesn't start after installing, in the last week !!

Comment: Why was this question down voted ? @downvoter care to comment the reason for down vote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through each and every possible solution I could find on the internet in vain, the only obvious thing to do was to say Good Bye to NetBeans and switch to another IDE.